# Java ASM is not visiting all methods of my AdviceAdapter

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I am a beginner to ASM and bytecode instrumentation and trying to learn with a simple example. I want to visit all methods of all classes loaded and mark/print as method visited.

Attached is my program but it is not working as expected. Only few methods of each loaded class are visited and rest are ignored. Don't seem to understand on what basis some are visited and some are ignored.

For example when "javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet" class is loaded, it is calling visitMethod for only constructor and doGet method and ignoring rest of the methods.

ASMAgent.java

```
package com.ag.asm;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class ASMAgent {
    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
        System.out.println("Starting the agent");
        inst.addTransformer(new AGClassTransformer());
    }
}
```

AGClassTransformer.java

```
package com.ag.asm;

import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;

public class AGClassTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class classBeingRedefined,
            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
        ClassVisitor cv = new AGMethodClassVisitor(cw, className);
        cr.accept(cv, 0);
        return cw.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

AGMethodClassVisitor.java

```
package com.ag.asm;

import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;

public class AGMethodClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {
    private String className;

    public AGMethodClassVisitor(ClassWriter cw, String pClassName) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, cw);
        className = pClassName;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
        cv.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
        if (mv != null) {
            mv = new AGMethodAdapter(Opcodes.ASM5, mv, access, name, desc, className);
            if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet")) {
                System.out.println("..." + className + ";" + name);
            }
        }
        return mv;
    }

    public void visitEnd() {
        cv.visitEnd();
    }
}
```

AGMethodAdapter.java

```
package com.ag.asm;

import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import org.objectweb.asm.commons.AdviceAdapter;

public class AGMethodAdapter extends AdviceAdapter {

    private String className;
    private String methodName;
    private boolean isProtected;

    public AGMethodAdapter(int api, MethodVisitor mv, int access, String name, String desc, String className) {
        super(api, mv, access, name, desc);
        this.methodName = name;
        this.className = className;
        this.isProtected = (access & Opcodes.ACC_PROTECTED) != 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMethodEnter() {
        // mark method as entered
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMethodExit(int opcode) {
        // mark method as exited
    }
}
```

Here one point to note is that if I remove AGMethodAdapter.java as custom adapter from visitMethod of AGMethodClassVisitor.java and just return what is returned from super class, all is working fine. Don't understand why AGMethodAdapter.java is not allowing some methods to be visited.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It’s hard to believe that ASM decides not to invoke `visitMethod` depending on what you will return *in* that method, as that would require precognition. How do you determine that the method has not been called?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cr.accept(cv, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
```

instead of

```
cr.accept(cv, 0);
```

Exception is not thrown out from java agent, so you are not able to see that IllegalArgumentException is thrown.